# Is enlightened awarded if you answer your own question?

Tags: discussion, badges, enlightened-badge

I have answered a couple of my own questions with a score of ten+; however, I never received enlightened badge for those answers.

Should you get the enlightened badge, if you answer your own question?

Comment: Do you want a [discussion] around whether Enlightened should be awarded to self-answers or are you asking for [support] in determining whether it is awarded or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> Be the first person to answer a question, and receive a score of at least ten for that answer. The answer must be accepted by the question owner, **and it mustn't be a self-accept**.

Comment: Thank you for the link, perhaps someone could add the last portion to the [badge descriptions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/badges)

Comment: @Mike valid request, you can start new question tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] and ask for that change.

Comment: That contains only a short description and not all if and if nots. The detailed list of all badges is for that.

Comment: @juergend I believe that information can be added to the short description without making it too long. In its current form it's indeed confusing and without link to the full description people have to start digging on Meta to find it out.